# Screen Rotation with Android Endless Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying the CommonsWare's android endlist adapter.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

After loading a couple of pages, i rotated the screen, and the listview loses all the pages except the first one. Doesn't it supposed to retain the loaded items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't it supposed to retain the loaded items?

That is your job, not the adapter's. Adapters do not "retain" "items", regardless of whether `EndlessAdapter` is involved or not.

By default, activities are destroyed and recreated when the device undergoes a configuration change, such as a screen rotation. You need to arrange to hang onto your model data when this occurs, by:

- using `setRetainInstance()` on a dynamic fragment, or
- using `onSaveInstanceState()`, or
- using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, or
- in the worst case, using `android:configChanges`, as suggested in another answer

Comment: OK @CommonsWare. Will it be different if i use a loader with the adapter?

Comment: @syloc: Well, `EndlessAdapter` does not work with a `CursorAdapter` AFAIK. That being said, a properly-implement `Loader` would help you retain your data across configuration changes.